# nginx wrongly redirected the site with $request_uri

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect http to https with nginx:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

and I get this

```
curl -I http://example.com

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: **
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://example.com/
```

but when I visit http://example.com from browser, it was redirected to https://example.comget%20/%20HTTP/1.1.uri which is not accessible.

I have googled but doesn't find a soluation.

Comment: solved! clear chrome cache and works now